# How to set in a textview how many times a button is being clicked?

Tags: java, android

If I click a button 1 time, so it should to show  number "1" in a textview. If I click again, so its should to show "2"...

```
@Override   
public void onClick(View p1){

    int id = p1.getId();

    double x = 0;
    //button clicked
    if(id == R.id.button_contar){
        x++;   /*its only shows "1". When I click again, shows "1" again*/

        this.mViewHolder.contados.setText(String.format("%.0f", x));
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using x++ use x = x+1;  and this counter x should not be inside the click listener's function! else it will cause to reset the value back to zero

Comment: @Rizwanatta That would not change anything.

Comment: Everytime when the button is clicked, onClick is called, i.e. double x = 0 is being called every time so with each click first you are setting value of x to be 0 then incrementing it by 1 which would result in 1 and textview will show 1.

Comment: Try creating the variable x outside your function. It will work. Although there would be much better ways to know how many times button gets clicked

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal Tyyyyyyyyyyyy bro, it works!. Now I understand my mistake.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to initially set 0 in the textview, and with every button click you first fetch the current value in textView and then increment the value and set the new Value

```
int id = p1.getId();
//button clicked
if(id == R.id.button_contar){
    int current = Integer.parseInt(this.mViewHolder.contados.getText().toString());
    current++;
    this.mViewHolder.contados.setText(String.format("%.0f", current));
}
```

I don't have any editor right now, so there might be some syntax errors with the above code. It will give you a rough idea on how you should solve your issue

Comment: Thank you bro. So I format the textview to int, so the first value is 0. Better way to do it I think. Ty again!